# Cleaning a Git repository with rebase remote branches

Tags: git, branch, rebase

We are aworking on a project with GIT, but the guy who launch the project and create the git repository doesn't explain to the team how to correctly and properly use GIT. I just arrived into the team last week and I have been charged to clean up the repositories which are all messy.

First of all, there are 13 sub-projects so 13 repositories to one only final project. And the 13 repositories has been badly used. For example, for all this repositories, There are **master** branches which are unused since the last march month... and there are second branch **develop** which is **directly** used by each developer.

Last week I tried to explain how to have a better use of git branching and commands to the new team, I think that It will be applied. But at the moment I would like to enjoy again a good branching model in our repository.

At this time, first, I would like to *rebase the remote branch develop on the remote master branch* to get an up to date master branch (in the end, she will be a "production" branch).

Then I would keep the develop branch which will be renamed *pre-production* and which will be used with a tag system for each delivery on the pre-production server

And to conclude I would have a third branch: the new develop which will be well used (with pull request etc.) by developers.

*So can I safely rebase the remote develop branch on the remote master branch ? Or there will be risks and conflicts for others developers ?*

*If it's not possible, which is the best way to correspond to the branching that I want to set up ?*

Thank you very much for your help.

Jean-Timothée

Comment: You don't want `rebase`. You want `merge`. Also, check out [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). IMO, there's nothing wrong with having one repository per project.

Comment: If the `master` branch is unused since march and they have a `develop` branch, I'd assume that they worked with the **git flow** workflow that uses the `master` only for holding releases and the `develop` branch as main development branch. 
Furthermore, 1 repo per project is perfectly reasonable in order to separate things. And (and please don't take this as an offence): if you don't know about rebasing one branch to another, I strongly doubt that you should do it.

Comment: And as a general rule: don't `push -f` to published branches. And this would be neccessary once you rebased `origin/master` to another branch...

Comment: @krlmlr: Thank you for your quick answer, indeed they are using git flow which is a good way to work, when it's well used. But, do you think that only use merge is a good way ? Because, at the moment the historic of develop branch is yet very dirty...

Comment: @eckes, Thank you to, As I said in my comment to krlmlr the developer who launch GIT doesn't explain to the team how to use git flow so we have some dirty commit in master and in develop branch to...
I think so, that is not bad to have a repository by sub-project but it's just that git flow has been not applied correctly for each of these projects.
Thank you for your advice for rebase, I have no problem to make good work with this with my own job, but the question was just for the rebase between to remote branches ;)

Comment: @jdelagorce: As eckes said, you usually don't alter branches that are published already. That's why merge is better than rebase. This won't clean up history, but why do you want to clean up history in the first place? -- To your questions: There **will** be conflicts with other developers if you rebase.